# to mistake sb1. for sb2. - who is sb1, who is sb2?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

When you `mistook A for B`, does that mean that you expected B, but it was A or that you expected A, but it was B?

Comment: It means  that  you  wrongly believed that A was B. ***Mistake*** (used with object): 
to regard or identify wrongly as something or someone else:
*I mistook him for the mayor*.http://www.dictionary.com/browse/mistake

Answer (score 1):

> I mistook apples for pears.

This means that you thought it were pears, when it actually were apples.